# Quickest way to read network data?

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, linux-kernel

What are the alternative methods I have for reading a packet of data in the quickest time possible?

**Writing a driver in user-space?**

I have never written a driver for a network card (although if it wasn't as difficult as writing a whole operating system I'd be interested?). Could I obtain the already-existing driver code which must exist in Linux somewhere and literally "porting" this in to the user space? Would both Linux Kernel driver and my driver try to compete for same packets?

**Not writing a driver, but accessing the network data immediately after the stack from the C/C++ application?**

I do not know much about this approach- so if someone could help here I'd be interested.

I am interested in implementing my own zero-copy techniques to get the packet data as fast as possible. This computer doesn't need to use normal internet- it could be a proprietary network connection between two computers (for TCP and UDP).

EDIT:

I mean *latency*, not throughput

Comment: What is your objective for "quick"?  If it is for throughput, that is one branch of optimization.  If it is for response time, that is an entirely different discipline.

Comment: Honestly, your best off just using UDP-- network is always going to be a bigger bottleneck than the protocol choice

Comment: In addition to what wallyk says, does it have to be TCP or UDP? Does it have to be based on IP? Does it have to be based on Ethernet?

Comment: @Joni- not really- just a wired connection between two computers?

Comment: Define the order of magnitude of "fast".  Do you need to see the packet within 1μs? 1ms? The answer depends on your requirements.

Comment: @JimGarrison How does that possibly alter the answer? The fastest is the fastest if you can do in on 1 mirco then the 1 milli answer isnt the fastest.

Comment: So something like remote direct memory access could be acceptable? Things I read about Infiniband quote microsecond-scale latencies, but, of course, the hardware is pricey. What do you need this for anyway?

Comment: My question goes to aligning effort with requirements.  If the requirement is 1ms the there's no point investigating microsecond approaches.

Comment: @Joni- no special hardware - I just want to know how to access a network packet as quickly as possible in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowest latency for receiving packets in Linux is, as you say, to bypass the Linux kernel, which requires special drivers.  High-end network adapters from Mellanox, Solarflare, Myricom, Chelsio, etc. provide kernel bypass software.  For example, Mellanox claims you can receive a packet in under 2 microseconds with their ConnectX-3 card and VMA 6.0 software

> This week Mellanox announced the newest version of its VMA 6.0
>   Messaging Accelerator, which includes enhanced TCP and UDP
>   acceleration support over ConnectX-3 VPI adapter cards. With ultra-low
>   UDP latency under 1.4 microseconds and TCP socket latency under 1.7
>   microseconds, this messaging technology is reportedly more than two
>   times faster than competitive offerings.

http://insidehpc.com/2012/01/10/interview-mellanox-vma-6-0-tackles-latency-for-high-frequency-trading/

Comment: What would be the next level up from writing a driver? Could I intercept the packets once they have finished propagating through the Linux kernel driver code? If we remain on drivers- couldn't I "steal" the driver code currently in the kernel and put it in my app?

Comment: You could share buffers between the kernel and user space, see

http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt

Comment: Also see this presentation on Low Latency Sockets by Intel's Jesse Brandenburg 
http://www.linuxplumbersconf.org/2012/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/2012-lpc-Low-Latency-Sockets-slides-brandeburg.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I would say that using PCap should be fast enough. They have also modified version for linux with improved performance - [PF_RING](http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/) / [PF_RING DNA](http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/DNA/).

Comment: Yes, the PF_RING is an existing solutio, witch is mature. It meet the first approach that "Writing a driver". And most impoertant, it is free(In DNA, you should pay a license, witch supplies 10G line-rate capture).